# Count the occurrences of the key and number format

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my reducer part of MapReduce, I have the code

```
 public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text textValue = new Text();
    private FloatWritable floatWritable = new FloatWritable();

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      double total = 0.00;
      int count = 0;
      for (Text val: values) {

          String line = val.toString();
          String[] field = line.split(",");

          count+=1;
          total += Float.parseFloat(field[1]);          

       }     
       String v = String.valueOf(count) + "," + String.valueOf(total);
       textValue.set(v);
       context.write(key, textValue);
   }
}
```

However, the output returns 1 for every key but not the occurrences of the key. Also, how can I format the total to a number that has "," for a thousand value with 2 decimals?

Current Output

```
1     1, 1201.22135
```

Desired Output

```
1     3, 1,201.22
```

(3 is number of occurrences of key 1 and 1,201.22 is the total value of all key 1)

Comment: What is this output of? As for number formatting, you can use  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-, i.e. something like `String v = String.format("%d, %,.2f", count, total);` in your case.

Comment: The output is of the following data sample 3 columns: column 1 is the PickupID, column 2 is the DropOffID, and column 3 is the Fare Amount. In the Mapper part, I mapped <Key:Column 1, Value: a string of (Column 2, Column 3)>. In the Reducer part, I want to find the occurrences or frequency of each PickupID in the column 1 and aggregate the Fare Amount in the column 3. I used the "count++" but the outputs return only 1 occurrence instead of the correct number of frequency of each PickupID.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure there are 3 elements in `values`?